# Непонятная реклама на сайте через iphone

Tags: вирусы, реклама

При просмотре сайта teoremaschool.ru на iphone появляется какая-то непонятная реклама. Причем, как на safari, так и на хроме. Это вирус на самом сайте или на телефоне?

При заходе на сайт через ноутбук - рекламы нет. С друого телефона тоже пробовал - нет рекламы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это может, например, подсовывать интернет-провайдер. Почему вы уверены, что не сайт для моб версии возвращает баннеры? Вы можете у браузера на десктопе указать User-Agent телефона (через плагин, например) и проверить если ли реклама. Вирус на телефоне тоже нельзя исключать

Comment: Посмотрите источник рекламы в первую очередь. Мне через user agent свитчер на нескольких устройствах мобильных никакой рекламы не показало.